# Identify the color values of an image with a color palette using PIL/Pillow

Tags: python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library, pixel

I'm trying to identify the colors of the used color palette of an image with PIL/pillow.
I've tried the following:

- `image[x,y]`: this will only give me the index number of the corresponding pixel (i.e. `1`)
- `image.getpixel((x,y))`: again, this will only give me the index number of the corresponding pixel (i.e. `1`)
- `image.getcolors()`: This will give me the number of pixels and their corresponding index number (i.e. `[(2, 1), (2, 0)]`)
- `image.palette`: Returns a "PIL.ImagePalette.ImagePalette object"
- `image.getpalette()`: Returns a large array of (to me seemingly) unrelated integers (i.e. `[0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3 ,3 ...]`)

As an absolute fallback, I could convert the image mode and then get the color values, but I'd rather not if possible.

With this [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke2hD.png) (2x2 pixel image, indexed mode with 2 colors created with GIMP, the top two pixels are red (255,0,0) the bottom two are blue (0,0,255)), I was expecting something like:

```
image.getpalette()
1: (255,0,0)
0: (0,0,255)
```

---

Edit: The closest I have is:

`image.palette.getdata()`: This gives me `('RGB;L', b'\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00')`. Is there any way to have this mapped to the index number. Here each three bytes would map to one index number, I'd reckon.

Comment: Combine `getcolors` and `getpalette`. Those "seemingly unrelated integers" are what you are looking for; they *are* important.

Comment: okay, thank you for the comment. How should I combine them?

Comment: `imgage.palette.colors` contains a mapping from `palette colors` to `palette indices`, e.g. `{(255, 0, 0): 0, (0, 0, 255): 1, (0, 255, 0): 2, (255, 255, 255): 3, (0, 255, 255): 4, (255, 255, 0): 5}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get and arrange the palette like this:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open image
im = Image.open('a.png')

# Get palette and reshape into 3 columns
palette = np.array(im.getpalette(),dtype=np.uint8).reshape((256,3))
```

Then just print `palette`.

```
[[  0   0 255]      <--- first entry is blue
 [255   0   0]      <--- second is red
 [  2   2   2]      <--- grey padding to end
 [  3   3   3]
 [  4   4   4]
 [  5   5   5]
 [  6   6   6]
 ...
 ...
 [253 253 253]
 [254 254 254]
 [255 255 255]]
```

If you want to count the colours and how many of each there are, do this:

```
# Convert Image to RGB and make into Numpy array
na = np.array(im.convert('RGB')) 

# Get used colours and counts of each
colours, counts = np.unique(na.reshape(-1,3), axis=0, return_counts=1)
```

That gives `colours` as:

```
array([[  0,   0, 255],
       [255,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

and `counts` as:

```
array([2, 2])
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you :) All there is left for me to do, is map the remaining colours to the index number and the corresponding count!

Comment: `colours`? Enjoy your tea, Mark - and, please give Earl Grey my regards! ;-)

Comment: The colours are already mapped. The first 2 in [2,2] means there are 2 pixels with index 0, i.e. blue ones. The second 2 in [2,2] means there are 2 pixels with index 1, i.e. red ones.

Comment: We should make a law in Stack Overflow image processing that nobody can use square images (because they never show you which way around to put row and columns indices) and also that nobody uses images with 3 rows or 3 columns because then it is unclear whether samples are RGB triplets or rows or columns! The ideal shape for small images in examples is 4,5,3 because it is clear which are rows and which are columns and which are RGB triplets and they can be printed out with no parts omitted. Setchell's Law :-)

Comment: oh wow you're right. I've chosen an exceptionally bad example. Thanks for the clarification!