# How to count pixel values satisfying a predicate?

Tags: python, image, numpy, filtering, vectorization

Given a NumPy array of shape `(8, 24, 3)`, corresponding to an HSV image of height `8` and width `24`, I would like to count the number of pixels satisfying some predicate defined by a function.

Usually with NumPy arrays, we could do something like this:

```
def isSmall(x):
  return x < 3

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

isSmall(a)
output: array([ True,  True, False, False, False])
```

At which point we could count the number of `True` values in the output?
Can I do something similar with a predicate that expects three values,
corresponding to the HSV values in the array of shape `(8, 24, 3)`?

Something like this:

```
def isRed(x):
    h, s, v = (x[0], x[1], x[2])
    return ((170 <= h <= 180 or 0 <= h <= 10) and 100 <= s <= 255)

a = image of shape (8,24,3)

isRed(a)
Desired output: array([[ True,  True, ..., False, False],
                      ... , ...
                      [False, True, ..., False, False]])
```

This throws a shape error however, since seemingly the entire array is passed to the function, rather than NumPy doing its filtering magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NumPy's [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing), and the [`bitwise_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html) and [`bitwise_or`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_or.html) functions (used as `&` and `|`) to combine these boolean arrays. At last, count `True` values in the resulting array using [`count_nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html):

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


def is_red(img):
    h, s = cv2.split(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV))[:2]
    idx = (((h >= 170) & (h <= 180)) | ((h >= 0) & (h <= 10))) & ((s >= 100) & (s <= 255))

    # Just for visual debugging
    cv2.imshow('image', image)
    cv2.imshow('red_mask', idx.astype(np.uint8) * 255)

    return idx, np.count_nonzero(idx)


image = cv2.imread('images/paddington.png')
mask, n_pixels = is_red(image)
print('Red mask:\n', mask, '\n')
print('Number of red pixels: ', n_pixels)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

That's my standard test image (although not compliant with [Setchell's law](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60539888/identify-the-color-values-of-an-image-with-a-color-palette-using-pil-pillow#comment107103926_60540628)):

[image: Input image]

That'd be the "red mask" according to your cut-offs:

[image: Red mask]

And, that's the output:

```
Red mask:
 [[False False False ... False False False]
 [False False False ... False False False]
 [False False False ... False False False]
 ...
 [False False False ... False False False]
 [False False False ... False False False]
 [False False False ... False False False]] 

Number of red pixels:  31938
```

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
OpenCV:      4.2.0
```

---

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) and [binary bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators):

```
a = np.random.randint(0,255,(8,24,3))

h = a[...,0]
s = a[...,1]

m = (((170 <= h) & (180 >= h)) | ((0 <= h) & (10 >= h))) & ((100 <= s) & (255 >= s))

a[m]

array([[  0, 154,  31],
       [  1, 101,  63],
       [  7, 118, 112],
       [179, 154,  13],
       [170, 163,  58],
       [176, 105, 143],
       [  2, 237, 161],
       [  1, 107,  33],
       [  3, 152, 235],
       [  8, 233, 231],
       [  4, 128,  47],
       [174, 165,  75]])
```